# Having problems seeing polygons in my cocos2d code. Using cocos2d and box2d. Only in debug mode the actual polygons are visible

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

So I need help figuring out what code I am missing here. I have checked all over the place, but I need specifics on wether its the formulas used or a typo that i haven't noticed yet.
Here is the polygon class. I am trying to create random polygons with 8 vertices and then of course fill with a plain color. But I want them to continue to generate random position but leave them fixed. In a better way the poly's are my terrain.Ok revise: the polygons are there and my character interacts with them, but I cannot see them, and yes they are on the same layer. Oh but they don't keep generating at the bottom, which i am guessing i just need to delete the old ones once they go off the screen and it should make a new poly.

```
-(void) genBody:(b2World *)world pos:(CGPoint *)pos {
//Here we generate a somewhat random convex polygon by sampling
//the "eccentric anomaly" of an ellipse with randomly generated
//x and y scaling constants (a,b). The algorithm is limited by
//the parameter max_verts, and has a number of tunable minimal
//and scaling values.
// I need to change this to randomly choosing teh number of vertices between 3-8,
// then choosing random offsets from equally distributed t values.
// This will eliminate teh while loop.
screen_pos = ccp(pos->x, pos->y);
float cur_t;
float new_t;
float delta_t;
float min_delta_t = 0.5;
float t_scale = 1.5;
b2Vec2 *verts= new b2Vec2[m_maxVerts]; // this should be replaced by a private verts ... maybe ... hmm that will consume more ram though
float t_vec[m_maxVerts];

// Generate random vertices
int vec_len;
while (true) {
    cur_t = 0.0;
    for (vec_len=0; vec_len<m_maxVerts; vec_len++) {
        //delta_t = t_scale*(float)rand()/(float)RAND_MAX; // wish they just had a randf    method :/
        delta_t = t_scale*floorf((double)arc4random()/ARC4RANDOM_MAX);
#ifdef POLY_DEBUG
        CCLOG(@"delta_t %0.2f", delta_t);
#endif
        if (delta_t < min_delta_t) {
            delta_t = min_delta_t;
        }
        new_t = cur_t + delta_t;
        if (new_t > 2*PI) {
            break;
        }
        t_vec[vec_len] = new_t;
        cur_t = new_t;
    }
    // We need at least three points for a triangle
    if ( vec_len > 3 ) {
        break;
    }
}
```

At least where the body is being generated.
then...

```
float num_verts = vec_len;

b2BodyDef BodyDef;
BodyDef.type = b2_staticBody;
BodyDef.position.Set(pos->x/PTM_RATIO, pos->y/PTM_RATIO);
BodyDef.userData = self; // hope this is correct

m_polyBody = world->CreateBody(&BodyDef);

b2PolygonShape polyShape;
int32 polyVert = num_verts;
polyShape.Set(verts, polyVert);

b2FixtureDef FixtureDef;
FixtureDef.shape = &polyShape;
FixtureDef.userData = self; // hope this is correct
FixtureDef.density = 1.6f;
FixtureDef.friction = 0.4f;
FixtureDef.restitution = 0.5f;

m_polyBody->CreateFixture(&FixtureDef);

for (int i=0; i < num_verts; i++) {
    // Convert from b2Vec2 to CCPoint and from physics units to pixels
    m_verts[i] = ccp(verts[i].x*PTM_RATIO, verts[i].y*PTM_RATIO);
}
m_numVerts = num_verts;
delete verts;
}


-(void) setColor:(ccColor4F) color {
m_color = color;
}

-(BOOL) dirty {
return true;
}

-(void) draw {
//[super draw];
ccDrawPoly(m_verts, m_numVerts, YES);

CCLOG(@"Drawing?");
}

-(CGAffineTransform) nodeToParentTransform {
b2Vec2 pos  = m_polyBody->GetPosition();

float x = pos.x * PTM_RATIO;
float y = pos.y * PTM_RATIO;

/*if ( ignoreAnchorPointForPosition_ ) {
    x += anchorPointInPixels_.x;
    y += anchorPointInPixels_.y;
}*/

// Make matrix
float radians = m_polyBody->GetAngle();
float c = cosf(radians);
float s = sinf(radians);

if( ! CGPointEqualToPoint(anchorPointInPixels_, CGPointZero) ){
    x += c*-anchorPointInPixels_.x + -s*-anchorPointInPixels_.y;
    y += s*-anchorPointInPixels_.x + c*-anchorPointInPixels_.y;
}

// Rot, Translate Matrix
transform_ = CGAffineTransformMake( c,  s,
                                   -s,  c,
                                   x,   y );

return transform_;
}
```

there is some stuff in between but its less important. I can post it if asked.
Then the update function, which is based in my game scene class.

```
-(void)updateObstacles
{
//CCLOG(@"updating obstacles");
int xpos;
int ypos;
CGPoint pos;
for (int i=0; i<MAX_OBSTACLES; i++ ) {
    // If there is no obstacle generate a new one
    if ( obstacles[i] == NULL ) {
        polyObstacleSprite *sprite = [[polyObstacleSprite alloc] init];
        ypos = int(_winSize.width/2*(double)arc4random()/ARC4RANDOM_MAX) -   _winSize.width/2;
        xpos = int(_winSize.height/2*(double)arc4random()/ARC4RANDOM_MAX) - _winSize.height/2;
        //CCLOG(@"generating obstacle at %d,%d", xpos, ypos);
        pos = ccp(xpos, ypos);
        [sprite genBody:_world pos:&pos];
        [self addChild:sprite z:1];
        obstacles[i] = sprite;
    }
    //CCLOG(@"position: %d, %d", obstacles[i]->screen, obstacles[i]->position.y); FINISH
}
}
```

Sorry if its sort of a mess I set this up quick, but pretty much what I want to do is have randomly generated polygons appear at the bottom of my iphone screen as my character moves down with gravity. I got everything else but the polygons working.
Thanks in advance for spending the time to read this.